Pyside6 QUiLoader needs to be initialised prior to QApplication?
Contrary to documentation/tutorials I've found online, and contrary to the general workflow of PySide6, I've discovered that QUiLoader needs to be initialised prior to initialising QApplication, or it doesn't work. Is this a bug or a new implementation? I'm aware that other people have asked about this, but no one has been able to explain if this is a bug or not. As I am about to start building a relatively large project in PySide6, I want as much clarity as possible on the situation, as I don't want to build a bunch of awkward workarounds only to discover I didn't need to do so.
When I attempt to run this code, lifted directly from a PySide6 tutorial online, it doesn't work; the command window just freezes and is unresponsive to command line interrupt:
import sys
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile, QIODevice

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ui_file_name = "tester.ui"
    ui_file = QFile(ui_file_name)
    if not ui_file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
        print(f"Cannot open {ui_file_name}: {ui_file.errorString()}")
        sys.exit(-1)
    loader = QUiLoader()
    window = loader.load(ui_file)
    ui_file.close()
    if not window:
        print(loader.errorString())
        sys.exit(-1)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())

However if I tweak the code and move the initialisation of the QUiLoader prior to the QApplication initialisation, as follows...
import sys
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile, QIODevice

if __name__ == "__main__":
    

    loader = QUiLoader()

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ui_file_name = "tester.ui"
    ui_file = QFile(ui_file_name)
    if not ui_file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
        print(f"Cannot open {ui_file_name}: {ui_file.errorString()}")
        sys.exit(-1)
    window = loader.load(ui_file)
    ui_file.close()
    if not window:
        print(loader.errorString())
        sys.exit(-1)

    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())

...it works fine!

Possibly related to QTBUG-117882. Do you use QWebEngineView in the UI? Please provide more environment info, such as OS and Qt (not PySide) versions.

OS: Windows 11 Pro version 23H2
Qt version: 6.7.0
Python version: 3.12.3
The UI widgets were made in Qt Designer, I've converted them to python code and can't see any mention of QWebEngineView, so unless theres something I'm missing (I'm a complete Qt beginner) then I believe the answer is no I don't use it.
Please let me know if you require any other environment information.

It's definitely a bug, if you are correctly testing your code. Why not post a bug report with a proper [MRE]?

Just here to say that it is most likely a bug and that it is still not solved as of October 2024.
